# Filling out vectors passed as pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Suppose I have this logical array with, which I want to split into the 1 part and the 0 part, creating two separate vectors.

So I came up with the following method:

```
void cut_and_uncut(long* input, int length, long* cut_part, int* cut_length, long* uncut_part, int* uncut_length){
  int i;
  int n_cut=0;
  for(i=0;i<length;i++) n_cut+=input[i];
  cut_part = vecallocl(n_cut);
  uncut_part = vecallocl(length-n_cut);
  *cut_length = n_cut;
  *uncut_length = length-n_cut;
  int index_cut = 0;
  int index_uncut = 0;
  for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(input[i]==1){
      cut_part[index_cut] = i;
      index_cut++;
    } else {
      uncut_part[index_uncut] = i;
      index_uncut++;
    }
  }
}
```

- `input` is the input vector of length `length` (so imaginative!)
- `cut_part` is the vector with the indices of the 1s, of length `cut_length`
- `uncut_part` is the vector with the indices of the 0s, of length `uncut_length`

(Note: `vecallocl(k)` is just a shortcut for `malloc(k*sizeof(long))` )

I call this function with

```
int len,len2;
long* cut_vec;
long* uncut_vec;
cut_and_uncut(split,matrix.m+matrix.n,cut_vec,&len,uncut_vec,&len2);
```

The two ints (`len` and `len2`) are correctly filled, but when I try to look into the `cut_vec` and `uncut_vec` vectors, segfault happens.

I have the hunch that I am doing something wrong with the memory, because I initialize the two pointers without them actually pointing to anything.. but then in the function, with the actual vecallocl, they should be initialized correctly.

When I print the vectors from inside this `cut_and_uncut` function, everything works.. when doing it outside (i.e. at the same level this function is called) it does not.

What's wrong?

Comment: "When I print the vectors from inside this cut_and_uncut function, everything works.. when doing it outside (i.e. at the same level this function is called) it does not." What heppens outside ?

Comment: Segmentation fault whenever I call cut_vec[0], for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void cut_and_uncut(long* input, int length, long** cut_part, 
    int* cut_length, long** uncut_part, int* uncut_length)

....
// inside the function you now use `*cut_part` instead of `cut_part`, etc.

if(input[i]==1){
      *cut_part[index_cut] = i;
      index_cut++;
} else {
      *uncut_part[index_uncut] = i;
      index_uncut++;
}
```

and pass not the (still unallocated) pointers but the address where they reside:

```
long *cut_part;
long *uncut_part;

cut_and_uncut(... &cut_part, &uncut_part, ...)
```

This way, modifications will be retained after `cut_and_uncut()` returns.

Comment: I have done precisely as you said, but it still does not work. Actually now it segfaults before finishing to fill the vector inside the function: I changed not only into `*cut_part[index] =i` but also during the memory allocation (`*cut_part = vecallocl(...)`).

If I add a print statement inside the two if statements, I see that only the first 7 indices are processed (i=0,...,7) and then it segfaults, inside the cut_and_uncut method)

Comment: You code, as I wrote before was still producing a segmentation fault but I was able to get it working with a minor modification:

after allocating the memory using `*cut_part = vecallocl(n_cut);`, i did `long* cut = *cut_part` and then inside the loop `cut[index_cut] = i;`.

With these changes, your answer works fine.